# scrapy recursive crawl upto a user defined page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

This may come easy to experienced users but I am new to scrapy and what I want is a spider which crawls upto a user defined page. Right now I am trying to modify the `allow pattern` in `__init__` but it doen't seem to work. Currently the abstract of my code is:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name         = "example"
    allowed_domains    = ["example.com"]
    start_urls    = ["http://www.example.com/alpha"]
    pattern = "/[\d]+$"
    rules = [
                Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[pattern] , restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id = "imgholder"]/a', )), callback='parse_items', follow=True),
            ]

    def __init__(self, argument='' ,*a, **kw):

        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)

        #some inputs and operations based on those inputs

        i = str(raw_input())    #another input

        #need to change the pattern here
        self.pattern = '/' + i + self.pattern 

        #some other operations
        pass


    def parse_items(self, response):

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        img = hxs.select('//*[@id="imgholder"]/a')    
        item = MyItem()
        item["field1"] = "something"
        item["field2"] = "something else"
        yield item
        pass
```

now suppose user enters `i=2` so I want to goto urls ending with `/2/*some number*` but what's happening right now is that the  spider is crawling anything of the pattern `/*some number`. The update doesn't seem to be propagating. I am using `scrapy version 1.0.1`.

Any way around this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have your `__init__` method called the `Rule` is already set-up with the pattern defined at the beginning.

However you can dynamically change it inside the `__init__` method. To do this set the `Rule` again inside the method body and compile it (something like this):

```
def __init__(self, argument='' ,*a, **kw):
    super(MySpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
    # set your pattern here to what you need it
    MySpider.rules = rules = [ Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[pattern] , restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id = "imgholder"]/a', )), callback='parse_items', follow=True), ]
    # now it is time to compile the new rules:
    super(MySpider, self)._compile_rules()
```

Comment: hi! would you mind giving a help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630771/scrapy-linkextractor-duplicating